# Django notification for new chat message using ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I have used this code to send messages for my chat app, but when I add notifications it doesn't work. help me please
Note: i use django-notifications-hq

```
def send(request):
if request.user.is_anonymous or request.user.is_active == False:
    return redirect('/accounts/login')
if request.method == 'POST':

    sender = request.POST.get("username")
    receiver = request.POST.get("friend")
    message = request.POST.get("message")
    message = message.strip()

    if (message == "") or (request.user.username != sender):

        return redirect('/room/'+receiver)
    if sender == receiver:
        return redirect('/')

    newmessage = Message(sender=sender, receiver=receiver, message=message)
    newmessage.save()
    if newmessage.save():
         sender = request.POST.get("username")
         receiver = request.POST.get("friend")
         message = request.POST.get("message")
         notify.send(sender, recipient=receiver, verb='Message',
                     description=message, level='light')

    return HttpResponse("message sent")

return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by *it doesn't work* ?

Are you sure you need to call *Message.save* twice ? What return value are you expecting from *Message.save* ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to send a notification if the user has a new message.